# THREE.js - making a little squishy 3D ball

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, physics

I am new to THREE.js. I have some questions...

can someone help me with simple squishing this ball when he contacts the border and change direction? or maybe just scaling the ball from angle of contacting border point? to make this ball little more realistic

some code: [Making rotating 3d sphere with velocity](https://jsfiddle.net/JonDevoS/qd4afevg/)

code from this theme:

[THREE.js - moving a 3D ball with a rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133918/three-js-moving-a-3d-ball-with-a-rotation)

```
for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++)
      if ((x & 1) != (y & 1)) ctx.fillRect(x * 16, y * 16, 16, 16);
  var ballTex = new THREE.Texture(canv);
  ballTex.needsUpdate = true;
```

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

If the ball is rolling when it hits an edge, it'd be really difficult to create a believable squish by using the `.scale` attribute, since that only affects its scaling along the x, y, or z axis.

The best way to realistically achieve this effect is to use a physics engine to detect collisions and morph the geometry accordingly. There's already [an example of this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=physic#webgl_physics_volume) on the Three.js website. You can look at [its source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_physics_volume.html) to follow along. Just keep in mind it uses [Ammo.js](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/) as its physics engine, so you'd need to learn how to use the Ammo API if you want to make modifications.

Comment: yes i saw this physics example but i don't need so much "realistics" and no need physics at all. just simple scale would be awesome. if with scale imposible so maybe it can be made with some matrix4 "applyMatrix" or something similar to this

Comment: No, sadly transformation matrices only perform 3 tasks: translation, rotation and scaling. There's no special geometry deformation that can occur with a matrix4. You can try playing with a sphere's scale with the ThreeJS editor: https://threejs.org/editor/ you'll see that scale can only be applied along an X, Y, or Z axis, and it squishes both sides equally, not just one isolated section of the sphere.

Comment: scaling both sides it's okay for me. just want to know how can i scale mesh from angle contacts?


example
if the another mesh contact my ball from left bottom i detect angle of contact Math.atan2(-(y2 - y1), -(x2 - x1)) * 180 / Math.PI; and have like 135 degress so how can i scale my ball diagonal?